# Is there any way to check only the required checkboxes?

Tags: checkbox, cypress

I am trying to only select limited items which has DOM as below:

```
<div class="checkbox-wrap">
    <div class="wb-checkbox">
    <input id="Account" name="Account" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Account" type="hidden" value="false">
    <label for="Account">Account</label>
    <span class="check-mark"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

For selecting all the items, I used following code:

```
it('Select all items', ()=>{
    cy.get('#WallTransportationModeId').select('Wallbee-Road')
    cy.get(':nth-child(n) > .checkbox-wrap > .wb-checkbox > label').click({ multiple: true, force: true })
    cy.get('#btn-save-transportation-layout-setup').click()
  
})
```

All the items are selected as well. But now I need to only select 10 first items.

Comment: Do each checkbox have some 'id' attribute?

Comment: @damithanuradha Yes. Each checkbox has id. I have added in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a filter method in between the selection (which grabs multiple elements) and the action

```js
 cy.get(<selector-that-selects-multiple-elements>)
   .filter((index, element) => index < 10)              // first 10 elements only
   .click({ multiple: true })
```

---

You can use any kind of javascript expression inside the filter function,

```js
.filter((_, element) => element.innerText.startsWith('A')) // labels beginning with "A"
```

---

Selecting random elements

```js
const totalCheckboxes = 20;
const numberToSelect = 10;

const randomIndexes = Array.from(
  {length: totalCheckboxes},                         // empty array 
  () => Math.floor(Math.random() * totalCheckboxes)  // map to random indexes
).slice(0, numberToSelect)                           // take as many as wanted

cy.get(<selector-that-selects-multiple-elements>)
   .filter((index) => randomIndexes.includes(index)) // apply randomness
```

You can get some repeats with this, which is probably not what you want. Take a look on SO for "non-repeating random numbers" and adjust this code accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to select random items from the checkbox?

Comment: Personally I don't like my tests to do random stuff, but technically it is possible.